# Can`t open files/programs in python

Tags: python

I'm making a voice assistance type program and I wanted the user to be able to open any program on their computer but most methods I'm using don't work or I missing something out.
Every time I run the code and chose the option to open a certain program the terminal tells me:

"**The system couldn't find the specified file.**"

```
#Opens any applications in the system
elif 'open' in command:
        command = command.replace("open","")
        os.startfile(command+".exe")
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Perhaps debug the program with a series of `print` statements to verify the text representation of the speech is accurate.  Additionally, at times the *explicit path* to the program might be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it but you are trying to find a file, not a Program. Now you only need to name the Program

Try:

```
elif 'open' in command:
        command = command.replace("open","")
        os.start(command)
```

Comment: `os.start`? From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile): _"Start a **file** with its associated application."_ Do you mean `os.popen`?